# Adding Solr sort criteria to named query in Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, solr, spring-data

I am trying to add a **sort** criteria to a Spring data Solr search.

I have seen methods for sorting search results (List<> .. after the data has been received from Solr) but not for specifying the sort order to Solr in the query.
The Solr query should look like....

```
http://localhost:8088/solr/books/select?fl=fullrecord%2C%20url&q=mod_date%3A%5B2012-04-17T11%3A38%3A15Z%20TO%20NOW%5D&sort=mod_date%20asc
```

I need to do this **in Solr** because the request is paged (there are potentially hundreds of thousands of results) and so only a limited number of results (one page) are returned for each query.
How can I add the "&sort=mod_date asc" solr query string?

```
// Catalog.findByDateChanged=mod_date:[?0 TO ?1]

public interface CatalogRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<CatalogDoc, String> {
    @Query(name = "Catalog.findByDateChanged", fields = { "fullrecord", "url" })
    public Page<CatalogDoc> findByDateChanged(String fromDate, String toDate, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem that the sort can be added to the call...

```
Page<CatalogDoc> results = solrRepo.findByDateChanged(from, to, 
                  PageRequest.of(pageNo, perPage, Sort.Direction.ASC, "mod_date" ));
```

Curiously it adds it twice to the command to Solr...

```
&sort=mod_date+asc,mod_date+asc
```